# Does Android allow incoming connections?

Tags: networking, firewall

Some posts explain, that Android OS has all ports open by default with a policy to accept all incoming connections. But od a "NetGuard" Android project they mention "Android does not allow incoming connections".

So, how is it and what is the default configuration of a netfilter in Android OS? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If open ports are accessible depends on the used interface. Wifi is usually not a problem, unless the phone is acting as mobile hotspot. The cellular interface should theoretically also work but 99.99999% of all users don't have a plan with a public IP so nobody really knows...

Comment: Yes. The default policy for INPUT chain is ACCEPT. As of Android 13, the [Net Daemon](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-13.0.0_r1) - which is responsible for managing firewall rules - nowhere calls `iptables --policy`, so leaving it to default. But it doesn't make much difference when you don't have any listening ports on public interfaces and you are behind (CG)NAT (which is usually the case as Robert mentioned).

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I don't see any issues when using cellular network. However it sound to me as a protentional vulnerability when using WLAN - it is basically the same situation as with ordinary PC (https://www.techrepublic.com/article/hundreds-of-popular-android-apps-have-open-ports-making-them-prime-targets-for-hacking/) there may be apps listening and vulnerable.
What confuses me is the quotation from NetGuard – my guess is, that Android maybe acts differently to the incoming connections when using VPN? (even when it’s not tunneling anywhere like in the NetGuard implementation)

Comment: In my opinion the chance of encountering an app that opens a port is lower than on PC. On a PC program any program can open a port and keep it open at any time. On Android this is only possible while the app is in foreground. For keeping a port open and provide a service on it it is a bit more difficult as to my knowledge you have to implement a background service. Thus the number of apps that open up ports (without user consent) is not very high.

Comment: All right, I've contacted the author of NetGuard and he states, that Android rejects incoming connections by default (and it has nothing to do with VPN). @Irfan Latif Are you sure about the ACCEPT policy? Robert is probably right about the probabalities, but considering the article mentioned above I am still interested in knowing how does it work.

Comment: @M_Ryan I've an almost always-active SSH server running on one of my phones which I use for CLI access and file sharing with my PC. And I always run FTP servers on my phones for data sharing with each other. I never changed firewall policy, which is utterly out of questions on un-rooted phones. I already gave you the link to the source code. You can check that `iptables --policy` is called nowhere. Furthermore you can uninstall all VPN / firewall apps, restart the phone and check if the policy is set to `DROP`, or if the incoming connections are `ACCEPT`ed or not.

Comment: But note that I'm talking about stock Android. Any OEM or custom ROM developer may change the default policy.